# Command to check the version of Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, service, tomcat8

I have launched an amazon linux machine. I have installed tomcat using this command

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install tomcat8.5
```

I want to know how can we start the tomcat service like we do in httpd (sudo service httpd start). Also is there any command to automate the restart of tomcat if the instance is restarted like we do in httpd (chkconfig httpd on) ?

Comment: Does systemctl start tomcat8.5 not working or service tomcat8.5 start?

Comment: Tried systemctl start tomcat it worked. Thank you so much....

Comment: Great, then you can use "systemctl enable tomcat" or tomcat.service to start at booth time.

Comment: Any idea which folder does tomcat get installed using the above command (`sudo amazon-linux-extras install tomcat8.5`)?